# How do I passing an input variable from one function to another without it asking for the input multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say that I want to take an input for variable `a` but then use the input in a function that will repeat but the function will change and save the input as a different value but as the same variable so I don't need the user input multiple times.

```
a = input("")

b = input("")

c = a + b

c = a
```

I save `a` equal to `c` so all the input I want is `b` but how would I go about repeating the function without repeatedly getting prompted for an input for `a` when all I want is to keep the value of `a+b`.

Comment: May be you need to read more about coding. Show some code you try before posting.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: To me, it's not clear what you want to do. I have the feeling that you just need to follow your tutorial a bit further, and the missing pieces will fall in place. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

you can do it this way:

```
a = "hello" 
a = a + "world"
```

`a = "helloworld"`

It will work the same for you also with `input()`:

`a = a + input()`